# Send ajax request from react component to local Node handler

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am a newbie in React/Node.js development. For learning these technologies I decided to use [react-webpack-generator](https://github.com/react-webpack-generators/generator-react-webpack) and I like it for the sake of simplicity. But I have a question. Can I send ajax query from React component to Node.js handler? In the browser, I always get 404 error, but I don't know why because my handler is located in the same directory as my component.

Example of code :

```
setAjaxQuery(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './fileHandler.js',
            success: function(){
               console.log('Success!')
            }.bind(this),
            error:  function(){
                console.log('Error!')
            }.bind(this)
        });
 }

render() {

    return (
      <div className="test-component">
            <button onClick={this.setAjaxQuery} value = "test" 
className="test-btn"ref="test">Test</button>
      </div>

    );
 }
```

[Result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvbm4.png)

Comment: A 404 response means that this route is not accessible.  This isn't a react issue, it's a server-side issue.

Comment: When you run code in the browser you don't have access to nodejs functions like that, you need to setup a server like express to create routes that you can hit via ajax